# Is regex in perl faster than in Java or other languages?

Tags: regex, performance, perl

I have heard from time to time from people, who said that regex in Perl is faster than in other languages. Also, some online documents also say Perl has advantages when it comes to regex processing. Can you guys explain if this is true, and why?

Comment: Not sure about Perl vs Java, but Perl's a helluva lot faster than plain old grep.  I once turned a 20-minute grep job of a huge file into a 15-second perl regex.

Comment: @Magnus: are you using the right locale? For me, grep is always much faster than perl because grep does not need to do additional operations such as capturing groups.

Comment: A few years ago, the text-processing programs in the gnutools supplied with Linux distributions (grep, sed, etc.) ran about 100 times slower when you specified UTF8 in your locale. (For example, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=538423 )

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why would you consider the speed of two engines when one of them (Java's) is notably buggy? (Search for writings by Tom "tchrist" Christiansen on the subject.) For example, `\s` fails to match many space characters.

> Also, some online documents also say Perl has advantages when it comes to regex processing.

Here are some:

- Has many features you cannot find in other engines, either because the other engines haven't copied them yet, or because their design does not permit them to support those features.
- Highly optimised. Many of these optimisations help to report failed matches sooner, something not covered by many benchmarks.
- A leader in Unicode support. It's support is so advanced that our developers are finding problems with the Unicode standard itself and have worked to have them resolved!
- Remarkly bug free.

Answer (score 13):

You may have a look at [this benchmark](http://attractivechaos.github.io/plb/). In the table, column `patmch:1t` gives the time on matching URL with `/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)://([^ /]+)(/?[^ ]*)/`, while column `patmch:2t` on matching URL or email with `/([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)://([^ /]+)(/?[^ ]*)|([^ @]+)@([^ @]+)/` (note the `|` operator). For the first pattern, Perl is about 10X faster than Java; for the second, they are about the same.

In general, Perl uses a backtrack regex engine. Such an engine is flexible, easy to implement and very fast on a subset of regex. However, for other types of regex, for example when there is the `|` operator, it may become very slow. In the extreme case, its match speed is exponential in the length of the pattern. Another type of regex engine is based on NFA. It is harder to implement but has stable performance (quadratic at the worst IIRC) for all types of input. [Russ Cox](http://swtch.com/~rsc/) has [several articles](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/) about these topics, which I like a lot.

I don't know what types of regex engine Java is using, but from the benchmark, its performance does not seem impressive. You may also be interested in [this benchmark](http://lh3lh3.users.sourceforge.net/reb.shtml) which evaluates several C/C++ libraries on regex.

EDIT: In both benchmarks, patterns are tested against an old version of Linux Howto. The vast majority of lines do not have a match.

About DFA vs. NFA: if I am right, a pure DFA cannot capture groups, at least not easily. Only NFA can capture groups. I heard that [RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) transform local NFA to DFA for the part of regex without group captures. I do not know if this is true.

On PCRE: PCRE has the same problem as Perl - inefficient given complex alternations. You may have a look at the [regex-dna benchmark](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/performance.php?test=regexdna) from the Computer Language Benchmarks Game. Versions using PCRE are all much slower than the fastest version that is using TCL (maybe PCRE is not using trie?). V8 is clearly the winner in that benchmark because [it does not use backtrack](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/02/irregexp-google-chromes-new-regexp.html). IMO, for C++ programmers, the best regex library is RE2.

Comment: Perl's regex engine is specifically optimised to find failed matches fast. Do the benchmarks to which you linked test this at all???

Comment: Perl uses tries for alternation, not an NFA. Your information appears to be a decade out of date.

Comment: @ikegami - the way I parsed the answer, NFA was mentioned as an alternate approach, NOT stated as being used by Perl.

Comment: @DVK, hum, I'm under the impression that Perl's engine is an NFA, and that the issue is that a DFA can be faster for some things.

Comment: @ikegami  - so, NFA for everything except "|"?

Comment: @DVK, Well, I don't have first had knowledge of whether it's NFA or not (cause I'm not sure what that actually means). But I do know that tries were optimised in 5.10 into a simple trie lookup.

Comment: @ikegami: after googling around, I guess trie is only used for a pattern like `/foo|bar/` where `foo` and `bar` are simple regex or raw strings. The 2nd regex used in the benchmark consists of two complex regex. I cannot really imagine how a trie can be used in that case. That may explain why Perl is very slow. Also, for the types of regex engines, Russ Cox's [article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) is a good start. Personally, I think Perl should switch to an NFA engine for the worst-case performance.

Comment: @user172818 yes, the trie optimization is used for alternations where all of the alternatives have known beginning strings. Also, if you want Russ's regex matcher in Perl, all you need to do is `use re::engine::RE2`.

Comment: 1) The docs to which you linked pretend Perl regular expressions are regular. It's hard to tell if it applies to Perl regular expressions or not. 2) The docs to which you linked say the following should takes 1,000,000,000,000,000 **years**, but it takes 40ms:  `time perl -e'($n)=@ARGV; $rep="a?"x$n; ("a"x$n)=~/^${rep}aaa\z/;' 100` There could very well be pathological expressions, but that's not one.

Comment: Your answer seems to raise more questions than it provides answers. I'm sure there's some good information in here, but it's so tainted.

Comment: The right test is `perl -e '$n=$ARGV[0];("a"x$n)=~/(a?){$n}a{$n}/;' 30`. This takes forever. `?` is an operator, not a symbol. It dramatically increases the backtrack possibilities.

Comment: I admit my answer is not well organized especially after the edits. Please read Russ' articles, which provide much more comprehensive background on the theory and implementation of regex engines and the problems with Perl/PCRE.

Comment: I know it's an operator. I used it as an operator.

Comment: It's the articles to which I was refering when I said "I'm sure there's some good information in here, but it's so tainted."

Answer (score 12):

The point is not that Perl is or isn't faster than Java (benchmarks tests will tell you), but that regexes is really (deeply) part of the language itself. Just an example, in Perl, no need to load any module to use regex. See [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/705078/465183)

Ex. a Perl *one-liner* in a pseudo-terminal (that prints the root's shell) :

```
perl -nE '/^root.*:([\/\w]+)$/ and say $1' /etc/passwd
```

How many lines do you need to do the same thing in Java ?

Perl is de-facto the reference language for regexes. That's why so many language use [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) engine (that means *Perl Compatible Regular Expression*)

Comment: Other kind of integration you won't find elsewhere: `'abc' =~ /(.*?)(?{ push @matches, $1 })(*FAIL)/;`

Comment: @ikegami - I'm tempted to ask that as a question, just so a good explanation would enrich SO.

Comment: @sputnick - the integration goes WAY WAY deeper than merely not needing to load a module (which, for a compilied language, is not all that much of a problem). It's things like ability to use `/e` modifyer, and support for named captures which make the integration so unique among others.

Comment: @ikegami: I recognize that line...